# NullReferenceException when running published website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, nullreferenceexception

I have a website that I published before adding it in IIS. After that I set the published website as the default website in IIS.

I got an error that the "Object reference is not set to the instance of an object" when I inserted values through form. There is no issues when the website is running in IIS without publishing. The error occurs when values are inserted using datagrid.

The error messages is as follows:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Admin_MasterEntries.gvwMileStoneM_RowCommand(Object
>   sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
>   +447    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowCommand(GridViewCommandEventArgs
>   e) +105
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs
>   e, Boolean causesValidation, String
>   validationGroup) +76
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +35
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +117
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +35
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs
>   e) +115
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +163
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +7
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +11    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +174
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5102

If any one knows please help me. Thank you.

Comment: when you see this error - do you get a stack trace as well?

Comment: Check what you do there: Admin_MasterEntries.gvwMileStoneM_RowCommand
Add more logic, add try/catch blocks etc

Answer (score 1):

That exception is caused by an object not being instantiated. Open the project and attach a debugger to the IIS process. A web service which is consuming the ASP.NET page is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Click your site in IIS
2. Open Pages and Controls section
3. Find ViewState group and check if ViewState is `enabled`.

Such solution helped me to solve null reference exception problem after publish.